# How can I transfer my BitCoins to my PayPal?

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins, money-transfer, paypal

How can I transfer my bitcoins to PayPal?

Comment: If you have them in an exchange like coinbase.com: (1) sell them into your bank account, (2) connect your bank account to PayPal, (3) transfer them from your bank account to PayPal. If you have them on your hard-drive, step (0) is to open an account on an exchange like coinbase.com and send them to your account.

Comment: @AlinTomescu It would be useful if you would write your response as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have them in an exchange like coinbase.com: (1) sell them into your bank account, (2) connect your bank account to PayPal, (3) transfer them from your bank account to PayPal.

If you have them on your hard-drive, step (0) is to open an account on an exchange like coinbase.com and send them to your coinbase.com account. Then go to steps (1), (2) and (3).